# General error: 1364 Field 'email' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'email' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `form1s` (`name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (jhiui, 2019-09-25 15:39:57, 2019-09-25 15:39:57))

My controller

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\form1;

class formcontroller extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request ){

    //dd($request->all());
        $form1=new form1;

        $form1->name=$request->yourname;
        $form1->save();
        $form1->email=$request->email;
        $form1->save();
        $form1->tp=$request->tp;
        $form1->save();    
        $form1->heading=$request->subject;
        $form1->save();
        $form1->text=$request->message;
        $form1->save();
        $form1->image=$request->image;
        $form1->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post your code as images... It's text; copy and paste the code into your question so we don't have to navigate to 3 different links to see your issue, and so we can easily help debug.

Comment: That being said, looking at your second image, don't call `$form1->save()` after every attribute. Add all the attributes and call `$form1->save()` **once**

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comments, don't call `->save()` after every attribute assignment. `save()` persists the data to the database, and if you're missing attributes (column values), you're gonna have issues. Also, this is very performance heavy, as you're calling an `insert`, followed by an `update` for every attribute... To fix this, just call `save()` once:

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $form1 = new form1();

    $form1->name = $request->yourname;
    $form1->email = $request->email;
    $form1->tp = $request->tp;
    $form1->heading = $request->subject;
    $form1->text = $request->message;
    $form1->image = $request->image;

    $form1->save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much dear. its fixed by you guide, data has been gone to database

Comment: No problem. Please consider upvoting/accepting this answer.